# Supress function output in R if argument missing

Tags: r, function, output, suppress

I'm new to writing functions and would like to suppress the output if a given argument in a function is not reported without having to write multiple return() for each potential statement. For example:

```
fun <- function(x1,x2, y){
    if(missing(y)){result<- x1+x2}
    if(!missing(y)){ols<-lm(y ~ x1 + x2)}  
return(list(result = result, 
            ols = ols))

}   

x1 <- rnorm(100)
x2 <- rnorm(100)

fun(x1,x2)
```

When you run this, you get an error since the OLS isn't reported (if you include a y, you get the same problem for the object 'result'). Without including a specific return() function within each if statement, can you suppress one of the return elements? Thanks for any and all thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `compact` from plyr, in combination with initializing `result` and `ols` objects as NULL at the start.

```
library(plyr)

fun <- function(x1, x2, y){
  result = ols = NULL
  if(missing(y))
    result <- x1+x2
  if(!missing(y))
    ols <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
  return(compact(list(result = result, 
          ols = ols)))

}   

x1 <- rnorm(100)
x2 <- rnorm(100)

fun(x1,x2)
```

`plyr::compact` removes NULL elements from a list

Comment: If you don't want to use `plyr::compact` you could use an sapply statement from base R by creating your return list object first then using  `my.list <- my.list[!sapply(my.list, is.null)]` then returning my.list

Comment: @scottyaz True, but using compact is less code I think, and I would assume most people have plyr installed anyway nowdays?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `try` function for error handeling:

```
try(fun(x1,x2),silent=TRUE)
```